# Passing SSM parameters to CodeBuild project securely

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, ssm

I have a CodeBuild project with buildspec that requires database password value to operate. I want this buildspec to be environment-agnostic, but each environment requires different database password. Database password value for each environment is stored in SSM store under it's own key.

What would be the better approach to pass the database password to the CodeBuild project in this scenario?

## Using CodeBuild's `env.parameter-store`

It seems that recommended approach is to use CodeBuild's built-in solution (`env.parameter-store`), but then I will have to load passwords for each environment and then to select one password in the build script:

```yaml
# Supported Variables
#---------------------
# - ENVIRONMENT
#

version: 0.2

env:
  parameter-store:
    DB_PASSWORD_PROD: "/acme/prod/DB_PASSWORD"
    DB_PASSWORD_STAGE: "/acme/stage/DB_PASSWORD"
    DB_PASSWORD_QA: "/acme/qa/DB_PASSWORD"

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - |-
        case "${ENVIRONMENT}" in
         "prod") DB_PASSWORD="${DB_PASSWORD_PROD}" ;;
         "stage") DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD_STAGE} ;;
         "qa") DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD_QA} ;;
        esac
      - echo "Doing something with \$DB_PASSWORD…"
```

This will require three requests to SSM and it makes buildspec more complex. Such approach looks sub-optimal to me.

Maybe there is a way to somehow construct SSM key using ENVIRONMENT variable in `env.parameter-store`?

## Pass SSM parameters from CodePipeline

The other approach would be to pass the password from the CodePipeline as an environment variable directly to CodeBuild project. This will dramatically simplify the buildspec. But is it safe from the security perspective?

## Get SSM parameters manually in CodeBuild script

Would it be better to call SSM from the script manually to load the required value?

```
# Supported Variables
#---------------------
# - ENVIRONMENT
#

version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - >-
        DB_PASSWORD=$(
          aws ssm get-parameter
          --name "/acme/${ENVIRONMENT}/DB_PASSWORD"
          --with-decryption
          --query "Parameter.Value"
          --output text
        )
      - echo "Doing something with \$DB_PASSWORD…"
```

Is this approach would be more secure?

Answer (score 4):

> **Using CodeBuild's env.parameter-store**

Looking at [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax), there is no way to dynamically construct the SSM parameter key and pre-loading parameters for each environment is just wrong. This would affect performance and have negative effect on API rate limits as well as will make security audit harder.

> **Get SSM parameters manually in CodeBuild script**

I guess this could work, but it will make the script more complex and would also couple it more tightly to SSM parameters store, because it will need to know about SSM store and key name structure.

> **Pass SSM parameters from CodePipeline**

Looking at [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_EnvironmentVariable.html) there is a specific environment variable type called `PARAMETER_STORE`. This allows to get value from SSM parameter store prior to invoking the CodeBuild build project.

I believe this is a cleanest way to achieve the desired result and it shouldn't affect security in negative way, because parameter would only be resolved by CodePipeline on build project invocation:

```yaml
- Name: stage-stage
  Actions:
    - Name: stage-stage-action
      RunOrder: 1
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Build
        Provider: CodeBuild
        Owner: AWS
        Version: "1"
      Configuration:
        ProjectName: !Ref BuildProject
        EnvironmentVariables: |-
          [{
            "type":"PARAMETER_STORE",
            "name":"DB_PASSWORD",
            "value":"/acme/stage/DB_PASSWORD"
          }]

- Name: prod-stage
  Actions:
    - Name: prod-stage-action
      RunOrder: 1
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Build
        Provider: CodeBuild
        Owner: AWS
        Version: "1"
      Configuration:
        ProjectName: !Ref BuildProject
        EnvironmentVariables: |-
          [{
            "type":"PARAMETER_STORE",
            "name":"DB_PASSWORD",
            "value":"/acme/prod/DB_PASSWORD"
          }]

- Name: qa-stage
  Actions:
    - Name: qa-stage-action
      RunOrder: 1
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Build
        Provider: CodeBuild
        Owner: AWS
        Version: "1"
      Configuration:
        ProjectName: !Ref BuildProject
        EnvironmentVariables: |-
          [{
            "type":"PARAMETER_STORE",
            "name":"DB_PASSWORD",
            "value":"/acme/qa/DB_PASSWORD"
          }]
```